# Dependency Injection with default Construction

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection

Most of my production code has fixed types of dependencies, illustrated below: the `House` for example, at run time, always depends on the same `Kitchen`.

Therefore, I am wondering what I gain by having the `House` **force** whoever constructs it to inject its dependencies as opposed to **provide the option** to inject the dependencies, i.e. provide both a default constructor and a DI-constructor?

What you lose by not allowing default construction is easily seen if you compare `mainDI` and `mainDefault`. 
Even if each class has only has two dependencies, if the dependency hierarchy depth is 3, as for example in the `House -> Bedroom -> Bed` path, you have to instantiate 2^3 objects in your top level class which seems unfeasible for large projects with a dependency hierarchy depth of 10 or more.

Having the DI constructor, I am still able to unit test a class.

So for all the DI experts out there, what is the downside of this approach?

```
struct House {
  House(Bedroom ib, Kitchen ik) : b(ib), k(ik) {}
  House() : b(Bedroom()), k(Kitchen()) {}
  private:
    Bedroom b;
    Kitchen k;
}

struct Bedroom {
  Bedroom(Bed ib, Lamp il) : b(ib), l(il) {}
  Bedroom() : b(Bed()), l(Lamp()) {}
  private:
    Bed b;
    Lamp l;
}

struct Bed {
  Bed(Frame if, Mattress im) : f(if), m(im) {}
  Bed() : f(Frame()), m(Mattress()) {}
  private:
    Frame f;
    Mattress m;

}


mainDefault() {
  House h()
}


mainDI() {
    Frame f;
    Mattress m;
    Bed b;
    Lamp l;
    Kitchen k;

    Bed b(f, m);
    Bedroom br(b, l);    
    House h(br, k);        
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Even if each class has only has two dependencies, if the dependency hierarchy depth is 3, as for example in the House -> Bedroom -> Bed path, you have to instantiate 2^3 objects in your top level class which seems unfeasible for large projects with a dependency hierarchy depth of 10 or more.

Make no mistake, you're *still* instantiating those objects **somewhere**.

> Therefore, I am wondering what I gain by having the House force whoever constructs it to inject its dependencies as opposed to provide the option to inject the dependencies, i.e. provide both a default constructor and a DI-constructor?

You gain visibility. If your main class *really* is the thing that decides what is instantiated deep into your hierarchy, that's a smell. A huge smell depending on the depth of the hierarchy, since your classes are leaking implementation details all the way down.

By hiding that behind a default constructor (or worse, and IoC container), you're hiding all of that coupling. You should instead work to remove that coupling where it makes sense. You'll get simplified constructors *and* all of the other benefits of decoupled code.

Comment: Do you mean "(or worse, a *ServiceLocator*)"?

Comment: @MetaFight - that is also worse, but not what I meant.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, then.  What's wrong with asking your IoC container to construct an object (and resolve its dependency tree) for you?

Comment: @metafight - it hides dependencies, hides coupling. And these days, abundantly overused. There are times it's useful, but it hides things worse that constructors that just make things for you.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing?  I'm not talking about parameterless constructors.  I mean using an IoC container with DI constructors that make dependencies explicit.  If that is an anti-pattern, what is an alternative?

Comment: @metafight - not an antipattern, just something to not overuse.

Comment: Oh, that I can get behind, then.

Comment: @Telastyn Thanks for your answer; you write: "If your main class really is the thing that decides what is instantiated deep into your hierarchy, that's a smell." I am not sure I understand: in my house example, who should build the Lamp?

Comment: @user695652 - the lowest part of the hierarchy that knows to build _that_ sort of lamp. Having that all the way at the top is unusual in practical programs.

Comment: @Telastyn, when using Poorman's DI I normally see the top class (unfortunately) knowing about the dependencies at every level of the application.  I always assumed this was a necessary evil.  There is an analogous problem in the IoC container world where all registrations either happen in config or in the bootstrapper.  The only pattern I've seen that deals with this problem is having Modules or Layers register their own interface->implementation mappings.  This, however, either requires reflection magic or the bootstrapper calling all module/layer registration methods.  Is there another way?

Comment: @metafight - in real programs, there's usually not _a_ `bed`. Usually there are some pre-constructed bundles. Either subtypes that know what their dependencies are, or helper functions to build the common implementations. One thing I've seen is using modules/layers but having a simple factory to provide the entire module/layer. Stuff like DataAccess often has many types that need the same dependency. Hard to describe without concrete examples. But yeah, sometimes the top level class knows about all of the bits. That's unfortunate, but better in my experience than some IOC configuration knowing

Comment: Is there anything wrong doing this if the default constructor is used to provide the only production instance we will ever have and the argument is only used to pass a mock in test code?
I'd have thought hiding an implementation details such as an AbstractFactory would be beneficial if we're confident we will only ever pass the one type of factory in production.

Comment: @DeclanMcKenna - if your code isn’t flexible enough to test, it won’t be flexible enough to accommodate inevitable requirements change over its lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

When using Dependency Injection you are not supposed to pass an exponential number of arguments through the constructor.  Instead you have an Assembler class (similar to a Factory) that can be configured to build objects for you from any configured class.  This should leave your class code clean, without an exponential number of parameters but also give you flexibility to change the implementation easily.

The problem with your approach is that you will have to pass an exponential number of arguments when you test integration.

Martin Fowler has a detailed explanation on how to use DI: 
https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection

Comment: I think you may be falling into the trap of assuming Dependency Injection can only be achieved using an IoC container.  This is false.  The *inaptly* named "Poorman's DI" is a perfectly acceptable approach to DI in *many* scenarios.

Comment: Yes, but the question specifically complains about the number of arguments that are needed to be passed down through different level of the hierarchy.  If you don't want to do that you need to create the dependent objects in your class by either directly constructing them or delegating this work to some type of Factory (IoC container, ServiceLocator, etc.).

Comment: @MetaFight I am also confused, how with the Poorman's DI you can get around the exponential blowup of things to instantiate in your Integration Test/Main class

Comment: @user695652 it doesn't solve that problem.  I was simply challenging the statement `Instead you have an Assembler class (similar to a Factory) that can be configured to build objects for you...`.  I was trying to highlight that even that isn't always necessary.  For simple applications Poorman's DI is a valid alternative.  In your case, however, it probably isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok for small solutions with one project/library.
In this case your `Home` class responsible for building objects it depends on.

For larger solutions, where `Home`, `Bedroom` and `Bed` classes are in different libraries, this approach will violate "Inversion of Control" principle. Because your higher level types will depend on lower level types.
So when you makes internal change in `Bed` class, you will need to recompile whole solution.

Instead if higher level classes depend on abstractions, then you can work with lower level classes without recompiling whole system.

In this case you will need to create one entry point project with `Main` method. This will be only project which will know about all dependencies and build whole object graph for your application.