# Manual DI and Managing Concrete Implementations

Tags: dependency-injection

Considering a solution that has some manual DI going on such as the below class, is there a better way of managing the concrete implementations without adding a container. This is theoretical, there is no real test case but something I was thinking of earlier.

The below DI example is fine, however it's preferred that concrete classes are kept to the composition root and not scattered across an application. Is there a way to achieve that without a container, or is this bit of a wild goose chase and containers are required if you want to achieve this objective?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass:this(new Something())
    {}

    public SomeClass(ISomething something)
    {
       //logic here
    }
}
```

//update
My question is not a duplication of the linked one. I will try to elaborate.

Usually with manual DI, I would have a parameterless constructor as shown in my code example, which calls into itself passing in a concrete class. Really there should be a composition root handling what is passed into the interface parameters and not a concrete defined for each class with a second constructor.

For small console apps etc this is manageable as Main is your composition root and where everything executes. However, on a asp.net mvc app for example, this becomes more complex. I was wondering what solutions if any other people have tried.

Comment: Um, what's the problem with passing `new Something()` as an argument to a constructor?

Comment: And just in case (though I'm sure you're aware of it): http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/ and http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

Comment: "The below DI example is fine". I disagree. The `public SomeClass:this(new Something()) {}` constructor removes the guarantee that dependencies will be injected.

Comment: Of course there is a way to keep concrete class creation in the composition root without using a container: you manually write the composition root. This is the key to pure DI (also known as "poor man's DI").

Comment: @Zapadlo I am aware of the composition root and DI in general, I have actually read a lot on the subject but my question is about how to handle the composition root without a container and without each class referencing its concrete in a parameter-less constructor

Comment: @DavidArno Do you have an example of how a pure DI composition root is implemented? In a small console app I can see it would be quite simple. Take something like a asp.net mvc application and it is a lot less obvious.

Comment: @James oh, you just haven't mentioned that your constructors are parameter-less. Well, things won't get drastically better, but you could instantiate no a concrete class `Something` inside `SomeClass`, but some factory instead. But passing it as an argument in constructor would fix this flaw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency Injection with default Construction](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344442/dependency-injection-with-default-construction)

Comment: @James, I do not have a real example that I can share unfortunately. But your observations are valid: manual construction of the composition root is easy for small apps. As they grow it becomes harder. At some stage, switch to an IoC container will simplify the process. I generally will use the manual approach for even large apps. Others shake their heads in disbelief at me and reach for a container for even simple tasks. Go with what suits you.

Comment: One thing I'd add though is that it's always worth putting the time into learning pure DI, before using IoC. Even if you then switch permanently to the latter, you'll have a better understanding of how its "magic" is achieved under the hood.

Comment: Pure DI is IoC. It just doesn't use a container. The stack article marked as duplicate isn't really what I was asking. I did find this however which answers perfectly. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/03/compile-time-lifetime-matching/